# Weird Fonts in Terminal

Tags: centos, terminal, virtualbox

I have ,

```
  CentOS Linux 7 (Core) x86_64 
  Host: VirtualBox 1.2 
  Kernel: 3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64 
  Uptime: 13 hours, 3 mins 
  Packages: 639 (rpm) 
  Shell: bash 4.2.46 
  Resolution: preferred 
  Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
  CPU: Intel i5-4200U (1) @ 2.294GHz 
  Memory: 186MiB / 1813MiB
```

See the screenshot below, This is what I see when I access my minimal centOS terminal from VirtualBox, I don't know what to call it how it gets to start to debug it.

[image]

It should actually look like this

[image]

However, when I enter from ssh everything is fine, its only in my VirtualBox command line. I hope at least someone can guide me in the right direction.

The issue most probably appears while I'm trying to upgrade my vim ( I'm guessing ).

Comment: akkilah, can you edit the question and explain what the screen in the image is about. Without clue about that, there is little we can help. It looks like you did a ls after a login. Is that correct?

Comment: does this help? https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-fix-the-display.html

Comment: @ruud I edit the question for more explanation. I will look into your link and update you -gods welling-

Comment: @ruud I can't believe it, it works. just `reset` . add it in the answer so I can accept it. tq

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dealing with garbage characters in bash is described [here](http://cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-fix-the-display.html). The command that fixed it here was `reset`.